# The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete.\r\nParameter name: tagObject VSTS Git API

Tags: c#, git, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api

I try to attach a tag to existing commit using **GitHttpClient CreateAnnotatedTagAsync** method (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.SourceControl.WebApi). But each time I keep getting error:

> The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete.\r\nParameter name: tagObject

Part of code for adding annotated tag.

```
GitObject gitObject = new GitObject { ObjectId = commitId, ObjectType = GitObjectType.Commit };
GitAnnotatedTag tagObj = new GitAnnotatedTag
{
    Name = tagName.Replace(' ', '_'),
    TaggedObject = gitObject,
    TaggedBy = new GitUserDate
    {
        Name = "FirstName LastName",
        Email = "someemail@smth.com",
        Date = DateTime.Now
    },
    Message = tagComment        
};

GitAnnotatedTag res = gitClient.CreateAnnotatedTagAsync(tagObj, projectName, new Guid(repositoryId)).Result;
```

Examples of tag objects I tried to send:

[image: TagObject example 1]

[image: TagObject example 2]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You code seems fine. I was using Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client version 16.143.1 to test your code. I was able to tag my commit successfully.

Comment: @Levi Lu-MSFT, thanks, I ended up using plain API to create tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just used API to create tags:

```
GitAnnotatedTag tag = null;

        try
        {
            var tagObject = new { Name = tagName.Replace(' ', '_'), Message = tagComment, TaggedObjectId = commitId };
            StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tagObject),
                Encoding.UTF8,
                "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json; charset=utf-8; api-version=3.2-preview.1");

            using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync(string.Format(createTagUrl, projectId, repositoryId), stringContent).Result)
            {
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();                    
                tag = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GitAnnotatedTag>(responseBody);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Add some error handling here
        }

        return tag;
```